# How to make component tags start with a prefix in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a project that I inherited from someone else, and I see a lot of `<p-xxxx>` tags, such as `<p-page :has-something="val1" :has-another="val2" />`, etc.(e.g. CompName -->

I'm looking around the directories and found a component called `Page.vue` that has such props in it: `has-something` and `has-another`. And structurally speaking, I'm sure the `<p-page>` corresponds to this component.

So how did this work? I checked the component's `name` field and it says `Page`.

EDIT: 
I should also note that the component isn't registered at all. It's not imported either. I'm guessing it has something to do with

```
import '@/globals';
import '@/plugins';
```

in `main.js`, because I know we're using our proprietary UI component library. Can anyone point to where I can go read more about how this works? I thought I was pretty good at Vue, but apparently not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

In our proprietary library we're using, components were being exported out with `p-` as a prefix, and the library was injected into the whole app via `vue.config.js`, so there wasn't any importing in individual components.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the component is registered in the parent component, for instance, if the `Page` component is registered as:

```
components: {
  PPage: Page
}
```

Then in the `template`, you'll refer to this component as `<p-page ...`

Comment: I didn't think about that, so I checked it, and it's not the case, so I edited the question to address that.